# Handle null value in relationship model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I use ember with parse database, and use embe-parse-adapter

but i got this error after fetch the records

```
Error while processing route: index.index Cannot read property '_relationships' of null TypeError: Cannot read property '_relationships' of null
```

From various resource i read, I suspect its because there are null value in one of field that has relationship with other model,

How i can handle this?

The javascript stacktrace is:

```
Error while processing route: index.index Cannot read property '_relationships' of null TypeError: Cannot read property '_relationships' of null
    at ember$data$lib$system$relationships$state$relationship$$Relationship.addCanonicalRecord (http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:106486:19)
    at ember$data$lib$system$relationships$state$has$many$$ManyRelationship.addCanonicalRecord (http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:106904:12)
    at ember$data$lib$system$relationships$state$has$many$$ManyRelationship.computeChanges (http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:107005:14)
    at ember$data$lib$system$relationships$state$relationship$$Relationship.updateRecordsFromAdapter (http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:106639:14)
    at http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:111256:26
    at http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:113058:20
    at Map.forEach.cb (http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:23060:11)
    at OrderedSet.forEach (http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:22853:11)
    at Map.forEach (http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:23064:18)
    at Function.ember$data$lib$system$model$$default.reopenClass.eachRelationship (http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/vendor.js:113057:83)
```

and the versions i use:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember             : 1.12.0
DEBUG: Ember Data        : 1.0.0-beta.18
DEBUG: jQuery            : 2.1.4
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 0.8.0-beta.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Comment: unless you show us some code we'll have no idea what's going on.